# Want to make Boss RC-505 mobile with batteries, do I need a choke?

Tags: power, batteries, choke

My Boss RC-505 Loopstation is a greaat bit of kit, but I'd like to make it more mobile (already done the 12v battery -> inverter -> 240 boss adapter -> loopstation) but it seems a little OTT when the input on the boss is only 9v @0.5A, never mind the form factor!

On the stock Boss power adapter they've fitted (near the connector to the boss) a dual coil choke - I assume to cut out interference from AC -> DC conversion from messing with the audio mixed with the loopstation - but do I need the choke if I'm planning to power with battery?

Also, any tips on battery or issues I might face would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ferrite beads aren't designed to block low frequency AC hum, but rather to reduce the amount of RFI from the device that is radiated back to the mains (e.g. from switching regulators) or noise pickup from it, and to stop the cable acting as a giant antenna.

For a battery application, you won't have those issues anyway, so in all likelihood the ferrite bead is not required.